# Javascript Push Notification for Backend Sync

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to create simple notes web application, that I can share with other people. When those other people make changes to notes, i want the notes in my browser automatically updates with those changes.

What options do I have? I've read firebase only supports chrome for web push notification, and APNs only supports opera. Is there a solution for all browsers?

Comment: You don't need push notifications to get data updates from Firebase to appear automatically in the browser or mobile app.  You just set up a listener on the data that you want to monitor, and it will be invoked whenever the data changes.  You only need push when the user needs to know of changes when they're not currently using the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the value event from the realtime database. First, make a reference your notes and than call the value event.

```
var notesRef = firebase.database().ref('notes');

notesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    $scope.note = snapshot.val();
});
```

Or, if you work with AngularFire, you can just create a $firebaseArray and loop the notes with ng-repeat.

```
var notesRef = firebase.database().ref("notes");
var notesArray = $firebaseArray(notesRef);
$scope.notes = notesArray; 

<div ng-repeat="note in notes">{{note.description}}</div>
```

Comment: does this work for all browsers though? it looks like it would use firebase push notification internally?